# AXIOS POST form submit to WordPress returning 200 with data returning 0

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, axios

I have a contact form which I am trying to POST the data via AXIOS using formData to send email via WP_mail.

Submitting the form seems to be working in the sense of:

1. The page isn't refreshing/adding parameters to the url
2. Using `for (var value of formData.values()) {console.log(value);}` to check what values are being grabbed by formData, `console.log` shows the different input values
3. `response.status` is showing 200

The problems start with `response.data` returning 0 rather than the data from the form that is being submitted.

**This is my form**

```
<form class="js-process dark-form">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">First name*</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your first name" />

      <label for="last-name">Last name*</label>
      <input type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Enter your last name" />

      <label for="email-address">Email address*</label>
      <input type="email" name="email-address" placeholder="Enter your email address" />

      <label for="telephone">Telephone*</label>
      <input type="tel" name="telephone" placeholder="Enter your phone number" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <label for="enquiry-form">Nature of enquiry*</label>
      <!-- TEMP -->
      <select id="enquiry-form" name="enquiry-form" data-label-value="test">
        <option disabled  value="">test</option>
        <option value="test">test</option>
        <option value="test">test</option>
        <option value="test">test</option>
      </select>

      <label for="your-message">Your message*</label>
      <textarea name="your-message" placeholder="Please tell us your message"></textarea>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

**This is my JS to POST the form data**

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const processForm = (e) => {

  const form = e.target;

  e.preventDefault();

  // let formData = new FormData(form);
  const formData = new FormData();

  // Console.log all formData values for testing
  for (var value of formData.values()) { console.log(value); }

  formData.append('action', 'contact_form');
  formData.append('first_name', 'my first name');

  axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: WP.ajax,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    data: formData,
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log(response.status);
      console.log(response.statusText);
      console.log(response.headers);
      console.log(response.config);
    },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  return false;
};

const initProcessForm = () => {

  const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.js-process');

  forms.forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', processForm);
  });

};

export default initProcessForm;
```

I'm not sure what I am missing here to get the data from the form to POST correctly. I know i've not even got round to the WP_mail side of things! I am new to using AXIOS so if anyone can point me in the right direction with this code or has a better way of doing this i'd be grateful to know : )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to change your headers into multiform?

Comment: Hi Mark, adding multiform doesn't change anything. The data form the form inputs is showing if i check console: Network > Headers > Form Data, all of what was typed into the inputs shows. Still getting status 200, but `response.data` is returning 0.

Comment: Worked out the problem, it was with the PHP mail function wasn't complete!

Comment: I was going to ask the function on the backend. XD
Good to hear that. :)